# On what object around a house would you find a "punt"?

Tags: word, knowledge

Someone asked me the other day:

> On what object around a house would you find a punt?

Comment: For your information, this puzzle is one of the floors on the discord server "climb the tower" which has a rule which specifically disallows asking for answers or hints online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a riddle, nor a puzzle of any kind. It's a trivia question. (It's apparently also being used in some Discord server's contest, but it's certainly not original to them either, so I'm not treating it as a contest puzzle.)

Answer (score 10):

Could be a trick question, but just in case it isn't...

> A wine bottle. The indentation on the bottom of the bottle is called a punt.

Answer (score 2):

It could be:

> A television set that is currently displaying an American football game. (In American football, a "punt" is [a particular way of kicking the ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punt_(gridiron_football)).)

Alternately, it could be:

> A very large grassy field that completely surrounds a house (so it's "around the house"), upon which some people are playing a game of American football.

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> An old Irish piggy bank?

Explanation:

> A punt is an Irish pound. I say "old" because of course Ireland no longer uses them (now uses the Euro instead).